# I'm comparing two variables with the same value but it says they're different

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

Well, I was asked to do a little job with SHA-256. I have to receive a user name and a password from the user (in console), change the password to a SHA-256 hash value and close the file (binary file). Then I have to read it again, getting its data and comparing it with new user inputs, checking if they are the same or not. A simple log-in system using SHA-256 hashing. The thing is, I write a random user name and password, but when I try to compare them later in the second step, it fails. The SHA-256 part comes straight out of the original code, it wasn't the point of this assignation.

I tried changing all my char arrays to strings, used, strcpy, strcpy_s and strncpy (just in case) and more, but it doesn't seem to work. Most of the codecomes directly from SHA-256 (my teacher sent it), but I'll put it here nonetheless

I'm putting the entire code in pastebin (it's kind of long): https://pastebin.com/W9jxsbK6

I don't know how to edit correctly in this text box, so please use the paste bin link.

```
struct Credentials {
char user[10];
char password[256];};

int main() {
Credentials c;
char user2[10];
char password2[256];
string test;
fstream file;

int opc;
do{
    cout << "Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "1.Create new user and password" << endl;
    cout << "2.Validate user and password" << endl;
    cin >> opc;
    switch(opc){
    case 1:
        cout << "Type the user name" << endl;
        cin >> user2;
        strcpy_s(c.user, sizeof user2, user2);
        cout << "Type the password" << endl;
        cin >> password2;
        test = SHA256::digestString(password2).toHex();
        strcpy_s(c.password, sizeof test, test.c_str());           

        file.open("credentials.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);
        if(!archivo){
            cout<<"Error...\n";
        return -1;
        }

        file.write((char*)&c,sizeof(c));
        file.close();

        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Type user name" << endl;
        cin >> user2;
        cout << "Type password" << endl;
        cin >> password2;
        file.open("credentials.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
        if(!file){
            cout<<"Error...\n";
        return -1;
        }

        if(file.read((char*)&c,sizeof(Credentials))){
            if(c.user == user2 && SHA256::digestString(password2).toHex() == c.password){
                cout << endl << endl << "User validated" << endl;
            }else{
                cout << endl << endl << "Error" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

} while (opc > 0 && opc < 3);
cin.ignore();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `if(c.user == user2`  This is not how you compare character arrays, or arrays in general.  At the very least, please post the `Credentials` class declaration, so as to show others the mistake you're making here, and can thus give an answer that will make sense now and in the future (since that link you posted can go away at any time).

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

`if (c.user == user2)`

Since `user2` is a character array, and `Credentials::user` is also a character array, that line is not how you compare two character arrays.  What that line does is compare two pointers, not contents of arrays.

The function to use is [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), or if you want to compare specifically `N` characters, the function is `strncmp`.

```
#include <cstring>
//...
if ( strcmp(c.user, user2) == 0)
{
   // strings are equal
}
```

Now, if `c.user` and/or `user2` were `std::string`, then using `==` to compare would have worked.  That's why using `std::string` is much more intuitive than using char arrays in this respect -- operations such as `==` actually work as expected.